# Does The YouTube API limit you to 500 videos for one search query?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am getting around 500 YouTube data for one search query.

I am using the code cloned from [youtube_tutorial](https://github.com/spnichol/youtube_tutorial).

```
def geo_query(video_id):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    video_response = youtube.videos().list(
        id=video_id,
        part='snippet, recordingDetails, statistics'

    ).execute()
```

Is there any way to extract all the YouTube videos without any limit?
Does YouTube limit you to 500 videos for one search query?

Comment: Even if the documentation said that there is indeed a limitation of 500
"Note: Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the channelId parameter and sets the type parameter value to video, but it does not also set one of the forContentOwner, forDeveloper, or forMine filters." (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters), there are workarounds.
Could you give the parameters you specify to perform your search query please to answer you more precisely ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to extract all the YouTube videos without any limit?

No for two reasons, the documentation clearly states you can have a maximum of 500 videos and secondly the quota cost would be huge.

[image: >Note: Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the channelId parameter and sets the type parameter value to video, but it does not also set one of the forContentOwner, forDeveloper, or forMine filters.]

Even if it didnt you would have issues with quota.

## quota math

The method you are using is [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

This method returns a max result of 50 rows per request

> maxResults unsigned integer
> The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5.

Each time you make a request you get 50 rows back you can then use the page tokens to request the next set of rows

> pageToken  string
> The pageToken parameter identifies a specific page in the result set that should be returned. In an API response, the nextPageToken and prevPageToken properties identify other pages that could be retrieved.

Now the request tells us that there is a total of 1000000 rows waiting for you.

```
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
```

At 50 rows at a time that would be 20,000 requests.  If we then check the quota calculator the cost for each request

> search list 100

The default quota is 10000 which would mean you can make 1000 requests before you run out of quota for the day.  So you should be looking at a max of 50,000 videos you could get back in a day.